# How to increase width for spinner field in android spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

The spinner in my main layout

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerEquipment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
```

And the spinner_border is this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
   </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/dropdown" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/dropdown" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/dropdown" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/dropdown" />
</layer-list>
```

I cannot understand how shall i increase the width of spinner width coz setting the value for android:layout_width for spinner part does not have any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
```

Decrease these values.Also `fill_parent` in `layout_width`

Comment: God Bless You Can you also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900536/how-to-fix-this-android-gridview-width-as-per-content and help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, Hope u will slove ur problem

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

or give some dp

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
```

if your working with LinearLayouts
try with Weights.